# How can capacitors pass AC without or with minimal voltage passing?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, ac, inductor

My question is: How can capacitors pass AC without or with minimal voltage passing?

If the current is caused by a voltage (potential) difference and current is just the voltage (or charge) passing per unit time across a cross-sectional area of the wire, then how can just current pass without voltage at high frequencies? What is flowing then?

This idea has confused me and I thought about how could it be possible.

---

Another similar idea that I had trouble with is how can an inductor pass voltage and not current at high frequencies? If voltage is passing, then how can current not be flowing across the inductor? How can voltage flow without current?

These are the 2 concepts that have been troubling to me.

The closest thing I could find on this subject is this: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_the_current_flow_through_a_capacitor_and_if_so_why

Comment: See if https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/431262/73158 helps.

Comment: @Transistor the link you sent does not answer my question. I am not asking why or how current can pass via a cap. Please refer to my comment that I made on Andy aka's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the current is caused by a voltage (potential) difference and current is just the voltage (or charge) passing per unit time across a cross-sectional area of the wire, then how can just current pass without voltage at high frequencies? What is flowing then?

Voltage and charge are not the same thing. They're not even measured in the same units: charge is measured in coulombs.

It's also important to recognise that "voltage" does not describe a physical thing. It's a property that can be measured in various circumstances, but it's not an object.

Charge carriers (usually, but not always, electrons) can be counted in coulombs. Each individual electron generates an *electric field*. The electric fields of nearby electrons add up to make a stronger field. All the classic "static electricity" experiments with rubbing balloons on things and hair standing on end? Strong electric fields.

The force that causes electrons to move along a wire is the electric field, and we can measure the difference in strength of field between two points in a circuit: that is what we call the voltage.

Within a capacitor, there are two plates separated by a *dielectric*. This passes the electrical field, but not charge carriers. So when a capacitor is charging, the electrons pile up on one side, and cause a change in the electric field, which pushes electrons out of the other side. But real charge does not actually cross the dielectric.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, I understand what voltage is now. You, and others, have corrected me about my idea of voltage.

Comment: Yes, this was the answer I was looking for. Thank you! I was asking my question with the wrong idea of voltage, which lead me to trouble with understanding caps and inductors.

Comment: Glad to help - this is a common misconception from "simple but wrong" explanations

Answer (score 2):

Within capacitors do not flow electrons. The dielectric material is indeed an excellent insulator.

In order to have current in a capacitor you need a time varying electric fields applied.

If the electric field is constant, than you got no current.

The time varying electric field attracts and push away electrons from the wires soldered to the capacitor.

The electric field displaces back and forth the fixed charges of the dielectric material.

```
Time          External E. Field         Displaced Charge          Current
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t = 0                                                                0
t = 1                <-                  -   +                      15
t = 2               <--                 --   ++                     10
t = 3              <---                ---   +++                     0 
t = 4               <--                 --   ++                     -5
t = 5                <-                  -   +                     -10
t = 6                                                              -15
t = 7                  ->                +   -                     -10
t = 8                  -->              ++   --                     -5
t = 9                  --->            +++   ---                     0
```

Comment: This is telling me what I already knew, but I like the table you made.

Comment: Displaced charge is not current. Your graph appears to show that the electric current flow and applied electric field are in phase (they are not).

Comment: Andy: you are 100% right. I indeed corrected the current column. Current and Voltage are 90 degrees out of phase. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a black and white situation.

> *How can capacitors pass AC without or with minimal voltage passing?*

The impedance of a capacitor falls linearly as frequency rises. This means that for a given AC current amplitude, if the frequency rose by ten times, the voltage developed across the capacitor would fall by ten times. Hence, at high frequencies, the voltage across a capacitor will be seen to be quite low for a given current passing. Clearly, this is capacitor dependent in that a very small valued capacitor will drop much more voltage at a given current that a much bigger valued capacitor.

> *how can an inductor pass voltage and not current at high frequencies?*

It's a similar story, as frequency falls, the inductors impedance falls and so, for a given voltage applied to the inductor, the current is ten times higher at (say) 100 Hz than it is at 1000 Hz.

Or, put another way, if the AC current flowing through an inductor 1 amp at 100 Hz, then it will develop one-tenth of the voltage across it compared to the same AC current at 1000 Hz.

It's not a black and white thing.

Comment: Inductors do not block AC and capacitors do not "allow" AC. It seems you are also thinking it's a black and white thing. Any answer that has useful information in it and does not contain falsehoods should not be down voted.

Comment: @MissMulan My question isn't really about why capacitors allow AC and inductors block AC. My question is how can current pass in a capacitor if the voltage lags behind? Because current is the flow of voltage, so then, what is flowing if there is a lack of voltage across the cap? Same thing for the inductor: current is lagging while voltage passes. If voltage is passing and flowing across the inductor, then wouldn't that be current? How can voltage flow if there is minimal current? I know it is not black and white, there are many steps in between.

Comment: @Andyaka when I say 'block AC '  and 'allow AC' I mean AC current passes harder through the inductor than the capacitor but you are right it is not black and white maybe I should edit my comment .

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful .It doesn't describe the process of why AC current passes easy through a capacitor and hard through an inductor.

Comment: @Shocked current isn't the flow of voltage; voltage and current are separate things. Voltage doesn't flow either; current flows. That's the terminology we use in EE. Is the this equation you are having problems with \$i = C\cdot \frac{dv}{dt}\$?

Comment: I see my mistake now. I confused charge and voltage when voltage should be the potential rather than the charge. I think I am starting to see why inductors can pass voltage now.

Comment: @Shocked are you relating the inductor with this equation: \$v = L\cdot\frac{di}{dt}\$?

Comment: @Shocked, "*I think I am starting to see why inductors can pass voltage now.*" Um, something wrong here. Inductors don't pass voltage, they pass current.

Comment: I know those equations, and yes, I am relating to them. @Transistor I have learned that it is hard for current to pass via an inductor at high frequencies (because inductors have magnetic fields and they don't like to change, and therefore, like to keep current constant), did I learn it wrong? I see it in every video and textbook, and they all say that.

Comment: @Shocked it's your usage of "passing voltage" that transistor is commenting about.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, I now know. I had the wrong idea of voltage. I am reading the new answer about voltage by pjc50. Voltage does not flow.

Comment: _"because inductors have magnetic fields"_ Again, you are trying to over-explain it. Inductors does not have magnetic field if no current is passing. Current though it will induce a magnetic field.